# pending migrations vs heroku rake db:seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm trying to deploy to heroku and I'm having an issue:
when i run heroku rake db:seed (which creates the admin user in my db), rails returns that I have pending migrations.
I've deleted these migrations manually (which I shouldn't have, I know), how can I go around this ?

```
Charlie@CHARLIE-PC /c/rails/rails_projects/METACRITIC (master)
$ rake db:migrate

Charlie@CHARLIE-PC /c/rails/rails_projects/METACRITIC (master)
$ heroku run rake db:seed
Running `rake db:seed` attached to terminal... up, run.1
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support
 for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them i
n your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initial
izers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonr
ails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required
)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support
 for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them i
n your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initial
izers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonr
ails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required
)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support
 for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them i
n your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initial
izers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonr
ails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required
)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
You have 2 pending migrations:
  20121013054027 Addcolumnimagetoshow
  20121013063205 AddAttachmentToShows
Run `rake db:migrate` to update your database then try again.

Charlie@CHARLIE-PC /c/rails/rails_projects/METACRITIC (master)
$
```

Comment: good news and bad news, I've managed to push my db (yay), bad news is I don't know how

Answer (score 2):

You were running your migrations locally (`rake db:migrate`) instead you should run the on heroku `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: I was not! I was just showing that rake db:migrate was running fine.